# Running executable file

Tags: 12.04, command-line, files, executable

I am pretty new to ubuntu and have done following.

I have made a file named PinkBunny using following commands and have written some text in it.

```
khan@ubuntu:~$ cat>PinkBunny
Hellow Guys!
^C
khan@ubuntu:~$ chmod +x PinkBunny
```

Now Since it has now become executable it now should be displaying its contents whenever I call it But following error keeps popping up.

```
PinkBunny:command not found
```

I know there is some problem in setting path but donot know how to do it?

Comment: What command are you using to run the script?

Comment: @troylatroy just typing PinkBunny in shell

Comment: Are you in the directory that the script is in? If so you need to put a `./` in front of your script's name without a space. Like this: `./PinkBunny`

Comment: @troylatroy That got this Error   bash: ./PinkBunny: Text file busy

Comment: You need an editor program with which the text file will execute and display its contents.So the command should be "cat PinkBunny" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to make your file callable like a script. Try using a bash interpreter like this:

```
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:/tmp$ cat>PinkBunny
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hellow Guys!"
^C
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:/tmp$ chmod +x PinkBunny
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:/tmp$ ./PinkBunny 
Hellow Guys!
```

Comment: That worked perfectly But could you explain me what /bin/bash is doing here and what does it do?

Comment: putting this special line will call a `bash` shell (see `man bash`) to interpret the rest of the file, here just `echo "Hellow Guys!"`.